# Python - Check using UTC timestamp if it is DST in another timezone

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, pytz

I have a UTC timestamp, I want to check if at that time, it was daylight savings in London. How would I do this in Python?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use os.environ to set your timezone. Here is an example checking for DST in two different timezones:

```
import time, os

os.environ['TZ'] = 'Europe/London'                                                                                                                                                      

timestamp = os.path.getmtime(filename) 
isdst = time.localtime(timestamp).tm_isdst > 0                                                                                                                                          


In [973]: timestamp                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[973]: 1571900789.0347116

In [965]: isdst                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[965]: True

os.environ['TZ'] = 'USA/Colorado'                                                                                                                                                        

timestamp = os.path.getmtime(filename) 
isdst = time.localtime(timestamp).tm_isdst > 0                                                                                                                                          

In [968]: isdst                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[968]: False
```

Comment: What is `filename` !?

Comment: Also, it can be crucial changing the environment Timezone.